# Spring 5 restful web services using reactor

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, project-reactor

I am building a resful app using spring 5, but getting exception. . .following is my code:

pom.xml

http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    com.spring
    spring5
    war
    0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    spring5 Maven Webapp
    http://maven.apache.org

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</spring.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.reactivestreams</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactive-streams</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor.ipc</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-netty</artifactId>
        <version>0.6.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
        <version>8.5.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web-reactive</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JACKSON -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- LOG4J -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.7</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<build>
    <finalName>spring5</finalName>
</build>
```

spring-config.xml

```
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
        xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

        <context:annotation-config />
        <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

        <context:component-scan base-package="com.spring5">
            <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
        </context:component-scan>

        <mvc:annotation-driven />
```

Controller:

```
package com.spring5.controller;

import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.spring5.bean.Message;

import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

@RestController
public class Spring5Controller
{
  @PostMapping(value = "mono-test", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = "application/stream+json")
  public Mono<ResponseEntity<Message>> monoTest(@RequestBody Message message)
  {
     return Mono.just(new ResponseEntity(new Message(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST));
  }

}
```

On calling the webservice from postman, I am getting following exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No converter found for return
>   value of type: class reactor.core.publisher.MonoMapFuseable   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:187)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:174)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:81)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:826)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:964)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:867)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:841)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:71)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

According to my understanding this is an issue with the negotiation manager, so is the negotiation manager configuration changed or or I need to add another message-converters for reactive classes. . .any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: You should be using `spring-webflux` as a dependency (that is the new name and not `spring-web-reactive` anymore). Simply remove your registered converters, those are already registered by defaultt anyway.

Comment: I cannot find anything by "spring-webflux" can you help me with the dependency

Comment: I have removed the contentNegotiationManager config, now i am getting the following error on client side: HTTP Status 406 - description The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers.

Comment: have a look at this recent blog post for more information about `spring-webflux`: https://spring.io/blog/2017/02/23/spring-framework-5-0-m5-update

Comment: I nowhere said  yu needed to remove the `contentNegotiationManager` I said that you need to remove your explicitly registered converters.

Comment: I have added the spring-boot-starter-webflux dependency and produces = "application/stream+json" in the controller and it is working now.. .thank you all for your help  @M.Deinum Kindly add your answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: @MohanSeth Hi Mohan, Coud you post the working controller code or the pseudo code so that it will be helpful for others